# Spring 3 + Hibernate 4 + JSF 2 + Postgresql 9 + Multi-tenancy - Connection Pool! Is it possible or not?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, multi-tenant

The situation is:

I am going to build a small web application (Spring-JSF-Hibernate, support only 2-10 internal users in my company). I decided to use PostgreSQL to store the data (around 10 tables - maximum 1M records on largest table - Simple queries-execute almost referent primary-key).

And i am finding a solution to "clone" this app to support many more companies (a server will handle at least 100 companies). I just new to SAAS and ["Hibernate Multi-tenancy"](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html)! and still thinking to decide between "separate database" or "separate schema". 
Only a few document about saas & multi-tenant. I am newbie and so confused.

Please help me to answer:

Spring 3 + Hibernate 4 + JSF 2 + Postgresql 9 + Multi-tenancy (separate schema)-Connection Pool!  Is it the right solution for my case?

Where can i find more info about saas & multi-tenant (Java)? Do we have any good reference resource?

Comment: And yes, it is a good call. But if you have some company support it would be wise to choose some more robust database like Oracle.

Comment: Thank you, Spring 3 + Hibernate 4 + JSF 2 + Postgresql 9 is the existing system, so i don't want to change it now. I just confused about Hibernate & Multi-tenancy - Connection Pool. Is it possible? and looking for an example/tutorial to implement it...

Comment: yes, sure it is. But you gona have a lot of work to do. So here is one  little article that may help, it have some code to test: http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/47817 and here is another example with code. https://gist.github.com/dipold/5700724

Comment: Here is another good one, it is about a framework http://www.athenasource.org/java/multitenancy-tutorial.php?part=1

Comment: Ok good luck. And when you have something done and functional, would you mind to share answering your own question to help others with the same need! :)

Comment: I also have same requirement if you find any solution then please share with me.

Comment: Why closed this! I am finding solution and repost on this thread.

Comment: Hi, Campos & lamba. would you mind to see my code in an new thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629611/multi-tenancy-separated-database-or-separated-schema-config. Plz help!